# In illustrator can I join multiple lines to form one huge compound path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I am making a map, and have a lot of roads which are a line with stroke. I want to join roads to form a network, without it adding extra segments. 
Is it possible to join one road onto a another at a midpoint (not at a free end)? I need to join them because of the stroke, as it shows if they overlap.

Comment: Why does it show when the roads overlap? Are the being multiplied? Or do the lines have multiple strokes?

Comment: If you won't be having to alter the paths in the future, you could expand the appearance of the stroked paths, then merge the newly created shapes together using your pathfinder.

Answer (score 2):

No It is not possible to join paths mid-segment. Paths can **only** be joined at anchor points, and only 2 path segments can be attached to any single anchor point.

The best you can do is to Group the objects, or utilize layers to organize things.

Comment: Thank you. I feared this might be the case!
If I made a whole lot of lines linked first and then added the stroke afterwards is there any way to do that? Can I combine them then, or does that only work with shapes not with paths?

Comment: @JennyPawsey you can apply styles to layers and groups yes. So the curve itself does not have to have a stroke or fill but if the group has than that gets painted (on top if it has other attributes in obejct). You select groups and layers with the round dot next to their name. So yes it does not have to be one object for you to ebale to manipulate it as one.

Comment: @JennyPawsey Here is what i mean, [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krq7Y.gif). The data in the layer is for all purposes one object except its not called one path it is group. So achieves same thing but gives you more control.